# SQLAlchemy server_default=text("now()") don't work properly

Tags: postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I have utc in db as timezone

but somewhere (no idea where) (+3:00) locale in in db I get not utc bat this (+3:00) time.

Any idea why? and how to fix ?

This is how table orm description looks like

```
class AccountingQueueInvoice(Base):  # created on invoice final approve by operator
    __tablename__ = 'accounting_queue_invoice'

    invoice_id = Column(ForeignKey('invoices.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    validated_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=text("now()"))
```

This is how i create a record

```
def create_accounting_queue_invoice(invoice_id, session):
    ref = session.query(AccountingQueueInvoice).where(AccountingQueueInvoice.invoice_id == invoice_id).one_or_none()
    if ref is None:
        info = AccountingQueueInvoice(
            invoice_id=invoice_id,
        )
        session.add(info)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was with

```
-bash-4.2$ cat postgresql.conf | grep timez
timezone = 'W-SU'
```

but in db

```
show timezone;
```

returns

```
UTC
```